# Producing plots from functions that bootstrap data

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, functional-programming, distribution

consider this data frame:

```r
set.seed(123)
dat1 <- data.frame(Loc = rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),each = 5),
                   ID = rep(c(1:10), each = 2),
                   var1 = rnorm(200),
                   var2 = rnorm(200),
                   var3 = rnorm(200),
                   var4 = rnorm(200),
                   var5 = rnorm(200),
                   var6 = rnorm(200))
dat1$ID <- factor(dat1$ID)
```

Location `Loc` is a grouping variable for the measurements `var1:6` on each `ID`. There are several pairs of `Loc`s that are so close to each other (geographically) that they should probably be considered a single group instead of two independent groups. Therefore I have written a function that will bootstrap each of the variables to see if these groups seem to have come from the same distribution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
BootT <- function(dat, var, gv1, gv2){
  set.seed(123)
  a<- dplyr::filter(dat, Loc == gv1)
  a2 <- dplyr::select(a, var)
  b <- dplyr::filter(dat, Loc == gv2)
  b2 <- dplyr::select(b, var)
  pooled <- rbind(a2, b2)
  boot.t <- c(1:999)
  for(i in 1:999){
    sample.index <- sample(c(1:length(pooled[,1])), replace = TRUE)
    sample.x <- pooled[sample.index,][1:length(a2[,1])]
    sample.y <- pooled[sample.index,][-c(1:length(b2[,1]))]
    boot.t[i] <- t.test(sample.x, sample.y)$statistic
  }
  p.pooled <-  data.frame(p.pooled = 1 + sum(abs(boot.t) > abs(t.test(a[,var],b[,var])$statistic))) / (999+1) 
 return(p.pooled)
  ids <- data.frame(Group1 = paste0(gv1), Group2 = paste0(gv2), Variable = paste0(var))
  p.pooled <- p.pooled%>%
    dplyr::mutate(Group1 = ids[,1], Group2 = ids[,2], Variable = ids[,3])
  p.pooled <- p.pooled[,c(2,3,4,1)]
 return(p.pooled)
}
#compare 2 locs of interest with a single variable
BootT(dat = dat1, var = "var2", gv1 = "a", gv2 = "g") 
#compare all 6 variables 
vars <- names(dat1[,3:8])
results <- list()
for(i in vars){
  res <- BootT(dat = dat1, var = i, gv1 = "a", gv2 = "b")
  results <- rbind(results, res)
}
```

I would like to modify this function so that it will output a classic histogram showing the bootstrapped distribution for each variable vs the observed value, and contain summary statistics on the plot. How can I modify this function to accomplish this?
Edit:
Originally, I was going to use the boot package to do this, which would have been easier, but I was not confident that I understood how the different arguments would change the sampling procedure. In situations where the two `Loc`s have equal variance (assessed with an F-test), I want to sample the pooled sample as I have demonstrated above. However, when samples are heterogenous, I want to subtract each groups mean before creating the pooled samples to compare (which forces the null hypothesis to be true, and makes no assumption about homogenous variance). For more info, see this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136661/using-bootstrap-under-h0-to-perform-a-test-for-the-difference-of-two-means-repl

I have actually made a very similar function (with another very original name) to the one above to deal with the cases where there is an issue of heterogenous variance:

```
BootT2 <- function(dat, var, gv1, gv2){
  set.seed(123)
  a<- dplyr::filter(dat, Loc == gv1)
  a2 <- dplyr::select(a, var)
  b <- dplyr::filter(dat, Loc == gv2)
  b2 <- dplyr::select(b, var)
  pooled <- rbind(a2,b2)
  xt <- a2[,1] - mean(a2[,1]) + mean(pooled[,1])
  yt <- b2[,1] - mean(b2[,1]) + mean(pooled[,1])
  boot.t <- c(1:999)
  for(i in 1:999){
    sample.x <- sample(xt, replace = T)
    sample.y <- sample(yt, replace = T)
    boot.t[i] <- t.test(sample.x, sample.y)$statistic
  }
  p.h0 <- data.frame(p.ho = (1+sum(abs(boot.t) > abs(t.test(a[,var],b[,var])$statistic)) / 999+1)-2)
  #p.h0 <- data.frame(p.ho = sum(abs(boot.t) > abs(t.test(a[,var],b[,var])$statistic)) / 999)
  ids <- data.frame(Group1 = paste0(gv1), Group2 = paste0(gv2), Variable = paste0(var))
  p.h0 <- p.h0%>%
    mutate(Group1 = ids[,1], Group2 = ids[,2], Variable = ids[,3])
  p.h0 <- p.h0[,c(2,3,4,1)]
 return(p.h0)
}
#compare 2 locs of interest with a single variable
BootT2(dat = dat1, var = "var2", gv1 = "a", gv2 = "g") 
#compare all 6 variables 
vars <- names(dat1[,3:8])
results.bootT2 <- list()
for(i in vars){
  res <- BootT2(dat = dat1, var = i, gv1 = "a", gv2 = "b")
  results.bootT2 <- rbind(results.bootT2, res)
}
```

If someone would like to explain how I can do these procedures and produce plots using the boot() package instead, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the following will run bootstrapped t-tests of 2 `Loc` of a variable `var` in data set `dat1`. It uses the [accepted answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/187630/171783) to this [CrossValidated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136661/using-bootstrap-under-h0-to-perform-a-test-for-the-difference-of-two-means-repl) bootstrap in function `bootTstat`, but this is called from function `funBoot`. Function `funBoot` is responsible for subsetting the groups `gv1` and `gv2` rows and the column `var`. The data set thus formed is passed on to `bootTstat`.

```
bootTstat <- function(x, y, R){
  pool <- c(x, y)
  xt <- x - mean(x) + mean(pool)
  yt <- y - mean(y) + mean(pool)
  boot.t <- numeric(R)
  for (i in seq_len(R)){
    sample.x <- sample(xt, replace = TRUE)
    sample.y <- sample(yt, replace = TRUE)
    boot.t[i] <- t.test(sample.x, sample.y)$statistic
  }
  p.h0 <- (1 + sum(abs(boot.t) > abs(t.test(x, y)$statistic))) / (R + 1)  
  list(
    statistic = boot.t,
    p.value = p.h0
  )
}

funBoot <- function(data, R, var, gv1, gv2){
  i <- data[["Loc"]] == gv1
  j <- data[["Loc"]] == gv2
  x <- data[i, var]
  y <- data[j, var]
  bootTstat(x, y, R)
}
```

For `"var2"` and groups `"a"` and `"g"` run a t-test with the entire groups data and `R = 1000` tests.

First the t-test.

```
a <- subset(dat1, Loc == 'a', select = 'var2')
g <- subset(dat1, Loc == 'g', select = 'var2')
t.test(a, g)
#
#        Welch Two Sample t-test
#
#data:  a and g
#t = 1.1002, df = 47, p-value = 0.2769
#alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#95 percent confidence interval:
# -0.2585899  0.8828038
#sample estimates:
# mean of x  mean of y 
# 0.1755209 -0.1365860
```

And the bootsrtapped t-tests.
R <- 1000
set.seed(123)

```
b_ag <- funBoot(dat1, R, var = "var2", gv1 = "a", gv2 = "g")
b_ag$p.value
#[1] 0.2737263
```

This p-value is similar to `p.value = 0.2769` obtained previously.
And the histogram can easily be plotted.

```
hist(b_ag$statistic, main = "Bootstrapped t-test")
```

[image]

Now run tests for all variables and groups `"a"` and `"b"`. Plot with package `ggplot2`.

```
ttest_list <- lapply(names(dat1)[3:8], function(v) {
  b <- funBoot(data = dat1, R = R, var = v, gv1 = "a", gv2 = "b")
  list(
    p.value = b$p.value,
    test = data.frame(var = v, stat = b$statistic)
  )
})

ttest_df <- lapply(ttest_list, '[[', 'test')
ttest_df <- do.call(rbind, ttest_df)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(ttest_df, aes(stat)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 25) +
  facet_wrap(~ var)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the tip, I started to use the boot package to do this, which would have been easier, but I was not confident that I understood how the different arguments would change the sampling procedure. Maybe you can help clarify: some `Loc`s have equal variance (according to F-test), in which case i want to sample the pooled sample as I did here, when samples are heterogenous, I want to subtract each groups mean before creating the pooled samples to compare (forcing H0 to be true, making no assumption of variance).

Comment: If that doesn't make sense, see this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136661/using-bootstrap-under-h0-to-perform-a-test-for-the-difference-of-two-means-repl   If this is something you could explain how to do with boot, (i would be greatful) i can structure my question more towards this idea

Comment: @Ryan Ok, thanks for the link, the question is now much more clear. (You should have included that link in the question.) I will take a look and return to this later.

Comment: @Ryan See now. Edited, completely changed and added links with references.

Comment: thanks for the help. I was working through your example, when I try applying your funBoot to a real data set which has unequal sample sizes (e.g., for a, n=12, for g, n=16), I get an error message: Error in t.test.default(sample.x, sample.y, var.equal = T) : not enough 'x' observations. I tried adding var.equal=T to the t.tests, but didn't help. any ideas?

Comment: @Ryan Yes, maybe include instructions at the beginning of the function to check the vectors' lengths and exit with a `warning()` in that case.

Comment: @Ryan `if(length(x) < 2) {warning("not enough 'x' observations"); return(invisible(NULL))}`

Comment: that's great thanks! would you be able to show me how to I could put the p-value of the tests in the top right corner of each of the `var` plots?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216570/discussion-between-ryan-and-rui-barradas).